# Rails, table style issue

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzIow.png)

I am learning a rails on YouTube and here I am having issues with table style. The video is old and rails are update already. However, I am following exactly what he is doing in the video, but I ended up with this weird looking table of friends list.

I want to put all friends info next to each other up-and-down like the video.

Comment: Impossible to say without any code (the output HTML would help), but I’m guessing there's a tag that has been closed too early or left open. Possibly a td or tr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this.

```
<table class="table table-sm table-bordered table-hover table-inverse table-responsive">
      <thead class="thead-inverse|thead-default">
        <tr>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Phone</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Twitter</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <% @friends.each do |friend| %>
                <tr>
                  <td><%= friend.firstname %></td>
                  <td><%= friend.lastname %></td>
                  <td><%= friend.phone %></td>
                  <td><%= friend.email %></td>
                  <td><%= friend.twitter %></td>
                </tr>
            <% end %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```